# After deleting my system python, how can I restore it?

Tags: high-sierra, homebrew, python

I stupidly deleted the system python on High Sierra, hoping to only use the Homebrew version. However, now I want it back. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the App Store and re-download and re-install High Sierra.
OR
Extract the files you deleted from a Mac that still has them.

Comment: Or restore from time machine or other backup